# Azure Shared Access Signature for whole storage account

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am using an API (node.js) to generate a read only shared access signature for an iOS app using Azure Mobile Services. The API generates the SAS using the following code...

```
var azure = require('azure-storage');
var blobService = azure.createBlobService(accountName, accountKey);
var sas = blobService.generateSharedAccessSignature("containerName", null, sharedAccessPolicy);
```

This works great when I want a SAS for access to one container. But I really need access to all containers in the storage account. I could obviously do this with a separate API call for each container but this would require hundreds of extra calls.

I have looked everywhere for a solution but I can't get anything to work, I would very much appreciate knowing if there is a way to generate a SAS for all containers in a storage account?

Answer (score 2):

You can construct an account-level SAS, where you get to specify:

- services to include (blob, table, queue, file)
- resource access (e.g. container create & delete)
- permissions (e.g. read, write, list)
- protocol (e.g. https only, vs http+https)

Just like a service-specific SAS, you get to specify expiry date (and optionally start date).

Given your use case, you can tailor your account SAS to be *just* for blobs; there's no need to include unneeded services (in your case, tables/queues/files).

More specifics are documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/azure/mt584140.aspx).

Comment: Thanks David, I'm following the docs but keep getting the error "Signature did not match. String to sign used was _acountname\nrl\nb\nsc\n\n2016-10-09\n\n\n2015-04-05\n"_. The token i produce is sv=2015-04-05&ss=b&srt=sc&sp=rl&se=2016-10-09&sig=7rdQIGkIwK+X01Q0YqFdFDGt8Li1SQt0u2riuSCyQZM= and the url  to get a blob from a container within the storage account is "https://accountname.blob.core.windows.net/containername/blobname?srt=sc&se=2016-10-09&api-version=2015-04-05&sp=rl&ss=b&sv=2015-04-05&sig=7rdQIGkIwK%2BX01Q0YqFdFDGt8Li1SQt0u2riuSCyQZM%3D". Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Hey what solution did you find on this ?